# Restrict concurrent content edit

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to **restrict concurrent edit** by the users.

If **user A** is editing a content then  **user B** should not be able to edit the content at the same time. That content should be visible, just not editable.

I am unable to find any module that provides this feature for Drupal 7.

Is there any module, or how can I achieve this programmatically?

Comment: Why don't you rather work with revisions? Locking content is always an issue. What if I start editing content, have it locked, and then go on vacation?

Comment: I cleaned up your language. Feel free to edit again or rollback, if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Yes, its good to use revisions for this purpose. But don't we have any module that lock the content so no other user can edit it. The lock should automatically get disabled if it is not being edited for some interval of time.

Answer (score 2):

This is old question but there is a module for restrict concurrent editing: [Content lock](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_lock)

> Block concurrent editing: When a user is editing a node, any other user that attempts to edit the same node will be blocked from doing so, and notified that the content is already being edited.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for that. Try the [Conflict](https://www.drupal.org/project/conflict) module

> This module allows parallel editing of nodes with field-level conflict detection and a trick to prevent accidental overwriting of fields when they are changed by another session while a node is being edited.
>
> This behavior is useful for things like issue queues where multiple people might be following up to an issue simultaneously.
>
> It works by hashing the field data and comparing these hashes. This is done so we can generically do a 3 way comparison between the original node, the node as edited by us, and the node as edited by others.

Comment: Can you please suggest any module or custom script that can lock the content for the time when it is edit mode. And release lock if it is not being edited for a particular interval of time

Comment: @Raj10 Did you try this module? BTW you're talking only about node edit right?

Comment: Yes, i did. Just want to lock content when it is being edited by other user. It should not be available for edit for other users